# String diagrams for duals with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arc

I would like to reproduce with TikZ the following diagrams [image]

[image]

It would be nice to have them rotated of 90 degrees (so to resemble cup and cap symbols). I have searched how to create arches, which however do not seem to suit my desired result: is there any simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like that suits you?

[image: simple archs]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[decorations.markings]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[arr/.style={
            postaction={decorate},          
            decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}}]
    
        \draw[arr=0.6] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[pos=0.6,right]{A};
        \draw (0,1) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=2] (1,1);
        \draw[arr=0.5] (1,1) -- (1,0)node[pos=0.4,right]{A};
        \draw (1,0) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=2] (2,0);   
        \draw[arr=0.6] (2,0) -- (2,1)node[pos=0.6,right]{A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arc`s as well. For the general shape, something like

```
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1)  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.5]
            -- (1,0)  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=0.5]
            -- (2,1);
```

Because the vertical lines are 1 apart, the radius of the arcs are 0.5. The `start angle` defines the "anchor" for the circle of which the `arc`  is part. For both cases, the `arc` should start at the leftmost point of the circle, `start angle=180`. Because the first arc goes counter clock wise from 180 to zero, I set `delta angle=-180`. The second arc goes clock wise, so `delta angle=180`.

Various examples, where I took the `arr` style for the markings from  [SebGlav's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/599849/), so credit to him for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  arr/.style={
            postaction={decorate},          
            decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{>}}}}
}
\begin{document}
% just simple shape
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1)  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.5]
            -- (1,0) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=0.5]
            -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

% same shape with arrows
% arrow positions found by trial and error
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  arr/.style={
              postaction={decorate},          
              decoration={
                 markings,
                 mark=at position 0.1 with {\arrow{>}},
                 mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}},
                 mark=at position 0.925 with {\arrow{>}}
            }
   }
]

\draw [arr] (0,0) -- (0,1)  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.5]
                  -- (1,0)  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=0.5]
                  -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

% separate paths
\begin{tikzpicture}
% first the three straight lines
% saving some coordinates for use later
\draw [arr=0.5] (0,0) -- node[left] {$A$} (0,1) coordinate (m1);
\draw [arr=0.5] (1,1) -- node[left] {$A$} (1,0) coordinate (m2);
\draw [arr=0.5] (2,0) -- node[left] {$A$} (2,1);

% then the two arcs
\draw (m1) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.5]
      (m2) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=0.5];
\end{tikzpicture}


% single draw, but with edge (which actually makes separate paths)
% because of edge, coordinates have to be repeated
\begin{tikzpicture}   
     \draw (0,0)   edge[arr=0.5] node[left] {$A$} (0,1)
           (0,1) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.5]
                   edge[arr=0.5] node[left] {$A$} (1,0)
           (1,0) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=180, radius=0.5]
                   edge[arr=0.5] node[left] {$A$} (2,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```